# xinput set-button-map not actually changing button map

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, button-remapping, xinput

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.
I want to un-map the last few buttons on my mouse because they're causing me issues.

The output of `xinput list`:

```
user@host:~$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Madcatz Mad Catz R.A.T.3 Mouse            id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Corsair Corsair Gaming K63 Keyboard       id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
...
```

The output of `xinput get-button-map 8`:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
```

I then ran:

```
xinput set-button-map 8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 0 0 0 0
```

but `xinput get-button-map 8` still gives me the same output.

I also would like this to be a permanent change.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried adding an xorg config file to make the change permanent and that seemed to do the trick. This is what I followed (I had to edit it for my mouse):

[Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/405073/making-the-xinput-set-button-map-changes-permanent)

For some reason doing it manually as I did in the question didn't work. I suppose it's because the mapping gets locked when the device is enabled or something? Only speculation.